# How to CAT multiple files from a number/date range in one line shell command

Tags: php, linux, shell, cat

I have a PHP page that runs queries to show and filter log archives in this format:

```
$output = shell_exec('cat /tmp/archive-08-10-2016-00.log' . $grepfilter);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

where `$grepfilter` is previously set to be a long pipe chain of greps according to pre-selected options (`eg. $grepfilter = " | grep -v \";OK;\ | grep -e WARNING | grep -v notthis";`)

What I need is to run this on multiple files from multiple dates using just that one shell command (or in a worst case run this one line command multiple times from a php loop). I searched and managed to find solutions for some of the requirements and here they are:

1) All logs from a certain date [**SOLVED**]:

```
cat /tmp/archive-08-10-2016-**.log
```

2) All logs from a certain month [**SOLVED**]:

```
cat /tmp/archive-08-**-2016-**.log
```

3) Range of dates withing one month (e.g. August 3rd-7th):

maybe something in the direction of `archive-08-[(03)|(04)|(05)...]`? doesn't work

4) Range of dates spanning across two months (e.g. July 29th- August 7th):

Comment: `archive-08-0[3-7]*` should do it.

Comment: Following your line of thought, if I need 3rd - 30th I can do [3-30] but the 0 in the beginning needs to be optional. Since I dont think ? works as it does in regex I need chars '0' or nothing, so does this look ok? {0,}[3-30]

Comment: it really depends on how the format is. I would probably say `archive-08-[01-30]-*`. Note by the way that here we are using [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), not regexp